# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop when passing states?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to access state from one component to another

FetchCompo.js

```
// import React from "react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//more imports

const FetchUserItems= () => {
   //some state
  const [userFirstName, setUserFirstName] = useState("");
  const [userItem, setUserItem] = useState([]);


  let userName = //somecode
    
  setUserFirstName(userName);

  let userItemsData= userData.MyArray.items;

  if (userItemsData.length === 0) {
    const emptyItems = [
      {
       //obj data
      },
    ];
    setUserItem(emptyItems );
  } else {
    //someData
    setUserItem(userItemsData);
  }

  return { userFirstName, userItem};
};

export default FetchCompo;
```

I wanted to use **userFirstName, userItem** in the another **Test.js** component.

```
// import React from "react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FetchCompofrom "../myFunctions/FetchCompo";

//more imports

const Test = () => {
 
  //Wanted to use userFirstName in Test.js component
  const { userFirstName, userItem } = FetchCompofrom();

return (
   <div>{userFirstName}</div>
  
 )
}
```

when I am trying to get the userFirstName, userItem in the **Test.js** component then getting error of Too many renders

looking for a solution how i can access these state **userFirstName, userItem** form one component to another.

Comment: Please, include your `useEffects`s to your question ...

Answer (score 1):

You're actually importing the **React Component** not the `FetchUserItems` helper function...

import FetchCompofrom "../myFunctions/FetchCompo";

**But you could do something like...**

```
const [userFirstName, setUserFirstName] = useState('');
const [userItem, setUserItem] = useState([]);

const FetchUserItems = () => {
  /** 
   * Make it plain helper function for fetching userItems
   * Do-not set-state here...
   */

  return { userFirstName, userItem };
};

export const FetchUserItems;

/** In your component ... say in useEffect */
const result = FetchUserItems();
/** setState here in case of result */
```

In `Test.js`

```
import { FetchUserItems } "../myFunctions/FetchCompo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `setUserFirstName(userName)` in `FechUserItems`, outside `useEffect` or normal function, this will provoque the component to re-render indefinitely because setting the states provoques re-rendering.

I would suggest to make FetchUserItems a normal function, because you are not rendering anything in it. You could use only Test comp for it.

The Test comp would be something like this:

```
// import React from "react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FetchCompofrom "../myFunctions/FetchCompo";

//more imports

const Test = () => {

   const [userFirstName, setUserFirstName] = useState("");
  const [userItem, setUserItem] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => fetchUserFirstName, [])
   
   const fetchUserFirstName = () => {
      // your code here and 
      // setUserFirstName in the end
}


 
  //Wanted to use userFirstName in Test.js component
  const { userFirstName, userItem } = FetchCompofrom();

return (
   <div>{userFirstName}</div>
  
 )
}
```